# get value from command log in cypress

Tags: javascript, logging, command, cypress

I m trying to get value from command log in cypress . I tried to get by css selector but I could not get the value. I tried custom commands but I couldnt get it .

On the webpage that I do automation test, there s a download button. when I click the button I got the exe file . and I can see the logs about download path and file But I cant get the path . I added the picture of the logs. Could you please help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to extract the folder path from the ui.

Instead, use this function:

`const path = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')`

It returns an absolute path.

You can also specify the [downloadsFolder in the config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts):